# Two-form wedge product

Tags: exterior-algebra

> Consider a two-form $\alpha$, then $d\alpha \wedge d\alpha$ is not necessarily zero.

Is this statement true?

> Consider  $\beta = \alpha \wedge d \alpha$. Then $d\beta = d(\alpha \wedge d \alpha) = d \alpha \wedge d \alpha + \alpha \wedge d^2 \alpha = d\alpha \wedge d \alpha.$

Is this statement true?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

$d\alpha$ is a 3-form. The commutativity relationship between a $k$-form $\omega$ and a $l$-form $\eta$ is

$$ \omega \wedge\eta = (-1)^{kl}\eta \wedge \omega  .$$

Also,

$$ d(\omega \wedge\eta) = d\omega \wedge\eta + (-1)^{k}\omega \wedge d\eta.  $$

The solutions should follow immediately from these properties (together with $d^2=0$). (For the second part, only the last equality is off. Edit: fixed)

Comment: Oh no, I meant $d\alpha \wedge d \alpha.$ I hope this is correct?

Comment: Ok, now it's fixed. Now the only question is, is $d\alpha \wedge d\alpha =0$? Here you use part 1.

Comment: Oh I got it. If $k+l$ is odd, $\omega \wedge\eta = (-1)^{kl}\eta \wedge \omega$ implies $\omega \wedge \eta = 0$. Otherwise it does now.

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear guidance. But just to be assured, how $d(\omega \wedge \eta)$ really work? I mean, $d(\omega \wedge \eta) = d\omega \wedge \eta + d \eta \wedge \omega$?

Comment: What you have is wrong. You need *both* $k$ and $l$ odd to deduce that $\omega\wedge\eta = -\eta\wedge\omega$. And look at @dc2814's formula above for $d(\omega\wedge\eta)$. It is the correct formula.

Comment: Thanks @TedShifrin, so it should be: "If $k \times l$ is odd, $\omega \wedge \eta = (-1)^{kl}\eta\wedge \omega$ implies $\omega \wedge \eta = 0$. Otherwise it does not"?

Comment: For the $d(\omega \wedge \eta)$ formula, it suffices to check this for $\omega=fdx^I$ and $\eta=gdx^J$ where $I$ is a $J$ are $k$ and $l$ multi-indices, respectively (this follows by linearity). $\; d(fdx^I\wedge gdx^J) = d(fgdx^I\wedge dx^J)$, and this can be computed using the formula $d(udx^I) = du\wedge dx^I$. Heuristically speaking, the $(-1)^k$ comes in when you move the $d$ past $k$ terms in the wedge product.